# Using GAE Blobstore API with Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, google-app-engine, multipartform-data, blobstore

I'm developing a Flex application that should run on Google App Engine. This app should be able to load larg-*ish* XML files (1 to 50MB) from GAE and save them again.

[UPDATE]

I'm using Java. The Flex app is already running on GAE - but can't yet load/save files. The  [Blobstore API documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Uploading_a_Blob) talks about using a multipart POST - how would I do this in Flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which language are you using in GAE, java or python?

What is your problem?  You don't know how to use the Blobstore API? Or you don't know how to use flex with GAE?

If you are using python Gae and do not have any idea about Gae with flex, you may have a look on the following:

http://aralbalkan.com/1333

http://fernandoacorreia.wordpress.com/2008/07/15/flex-and-python-project/

A little bite old, but very userful.

Update:

You can use the UploadPostHelper library to send the multipart/form-data in flex.  Please refer to the following site to get the idea on how to use this library:
http://marstonstudio.com/2007/10/19/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-a-flash-movie-and-automatically-upload-the-jpg-to-a-server-in-three-easy-steps/

Wish this can help.

Answer (score -1):

you want to load a 50MB XML file to the client? Why?

I have a fast internet connection but still 50Mb is a lot...

You can use PyAMF: http://www.pyamf.org/tutorials/gateways/appengine.html

Comment: PyAMF is really beside the point - he needs to send large files to the client, not send flash messages.